# Pycharm 2022.1.2 - Jupyter notebook with autoreload does not debug properly

Tags: python, intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Latest PyCharm as of June 2022 (2022.1.2):

When I turn on autoreload in a cell of Jupyter:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Debugging Python in a cell stops working. The debugger doesn't work and it just prints out something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myUserName/pycharm-2022.1/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_trace_dispatch_regular.py", line 429, in __call__
    abs_path_real_path_and_base = NORM_PATHS_AND_BASE_CONTAINER[frame.f_code.co_filename]
KeyError: '/home/myUserName/pycharm-2022.1/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_file_utils.py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myUserName/pycharm-2022.1/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_file_utils.py", line 580, in get_abs_path_real_path_and_base_from_frame
    return NORM_PATHS_AND_BASE_CONTAINER[frame.f_code.co_filename]
NameError: name 'NORM_PATHS_AND_BASE_CONTAINER' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

If I turn off the autoreload in Jupyter, then the debugger works exactly as expected, but then I lose all auto-reload-of-updated-code functionality.

I've googled extensively and can't find an answer. My PyCharm setup is pretty much stock and I think this must be occurring with many many users. I don't understand why something so simple and basic like this is still in issue in PyCharm in 2022.

EDIT: my PyCharm is configured with a mini-conda environment. Though, this is fully supported in PyCharm so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Is it reproducible in a new project with some simple code?

Comment: I rarely use notebook debugging but I have the same problem. For me the following works: I disable autoreload with `%autoreload 0` and reload modules explicitly via `importlib`. This does not update existing objects but it's better than nothing.

Comment: I experienced this issue after ugrading to pycharm-professional 2022.2.3. After downgrading to 2022.2.2 debugging in jupyter is working fine again.